# extend actionbar menu items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I create base activity with actionbar menu functional and extended another activities from it.

```
public class BaseActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        ...
        return true;
    }


}
```

Now I want to add some buttons to the actionbar in some activities. How can i add elements to actionbar and use element from base activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that as simple as in BaseActivity just don't forget to call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

**main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
        android:title="@string/action_help" />
</menu>
```

**home.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_new"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:title="@string/action_new" />
</menu>
```

In BaseActivity you are using base menu config `main.xml`.

```
public class BaseActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In child activity you are using another config from `home.xml` only with additional menu items, **no duplicates**. But don't forget to call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` with the same `menu` instance to add elements from `BaseActivity` (parent menu items would be added **after** child menu items if you call `super`'s method after inflate, and **before** otherwise).

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your actions for the actionbar in the main.xml

example :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
      android:title="@string/action_compose" />
```

And call from your subclass

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make different xml files containing the buttons you need specific to those Activity. Say for Activity1 you have two buttons and for Activity2 you have one, then you will create 2 xml files like below.

**action_activity1.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
   <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
    android:title="@string/action_compose" />
</menu>
```

**action_activity2.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
</menu>
```

Then in the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method inflate the desired xml file. Like,

**Activity1:**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_activity1, menu);
   return true;
}
```

**Activity2:**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_activity2, menu);
   return true;
}
```

Please be care full with the syntax (as I used appcompat actionbar). :)

This is what I use. Hope you find it helpful. And, I will be happy to see an easier way than this. :)

Comment: that's good, but I think this is not good way if you have one menu on more than 10 activities.

Comment: In that case I will have the BaseActivity implement this Menu so all the Activities unless specified a different one will inherit the same one.